# Java/Hibernate + HSQLDB java.sql.BatchUpdateException: data exception: string data, right truncation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hsqldb

I am testing an application locally using a memory-based HSQLDB.
So far everything went fine, however, when executing a testcase with a String bigger than 256 chars I ran into an error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: TABLENAME column: COLNAME
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
... 30 more
```

I gathered that the cause of this error is usually an "overflow" of the datatype one is using.

What bothers me is that I explicitly defined the column to be 4000 chars big, using the hbm.xml files.

```
<property name="translation" type="java.lang.String" length="4000">
     <column name="COLNAME" not-null="false" />
  </property>
```

When I cut the test string down to 256 chars or less everything starts working again. 257+ chars and the error is thrown. I don't really see the reason why this is happening. Why would HSQLDB define this column as length="256", when I explicitly state that it's supposed to be 4000...

Can anyone help?

Best regards,
daZza

Comment: how do you recreate the database?? Do you specify the SQL dialect in hibernate configuration?

Comment: Of course, I use the following for the HSQLDB:

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

and this for the real database:

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate

The recreation of the database structure works perfectly. All tables, columns, constraints, etc. are there and fully functioning. The only problem seems to be the length"256" thingy...

Comment: Have you checked the definition of the column in the database? Also: additions to your own question should be edited in, not as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for whatever reason HSQLDB seems to do a bad mapping for certain types and values specified in the config file to the real tables it creates.

I was able to fix the issue by changing the "type" attribute to type=text. Now everything works perfectly. I just hope that after I finish testing the application it still works with the original MSSQL DB and maps text to a varchar then...